# Forced Unwrapping in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation in which I need to get access to the streetName as shown:

```
if let street = john.residence?.address?.streetName {

    street // Darling Lane // This prints string correctly 
}

let street = john.residence?.address?.streetName! // Some "Darling Lane" The bang sign //  at the end does not forcefully unwraps the optional
```

Any reason why?

UPDATE:

Okay I am confused now! Here is the complete code:

```
class Person {
    var residence :Residence? = Residence()
}

class Residence {
    var address :Address? = Address()
}

class Address {
    var streetName :String? = "Darling Lane"
    var zipCode :String?
    var city :String?
}


let street = john.residence?.address?.streetName!
```

In the code above I am saying that if residence is not null them move forward. When you reach streetName then give me the value I don't care if streetName is nil just throw an error but evaluate it correctly.

The street parameter in the end contains Some "Darling Lane" and not the "Darling Lane". Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The `!` at the end of your optional chain only unwraps the optional `streetName` and not the entire optional chain as you expected.  Had `streetName` been declared as type `String` instead of `String?` or `String!` you would have received an error about trying to unwrap a non-optional value.

Had you done this instead:

```
let street = (john.residence?.address?.streetName)!
```

it would have worked.  Of course, if any of `residence`, `address`, or `streetName` were `nil` you would have crashed trying to unwrap `nil`.  That is why the first method you presented is preferred.

**Answer to UPDATE**

Only an optional variable can be `nil`. That is why the result of an optional chain has to have an optional type.

The type of `street` is established at compile time.  The compiler sees that you have a chain of optionals and makes `street` to be of the type `String?`.  It doesn't matter that you unwrapped the value of street at the end of the chain. Because `residence` or `address` could be `nil`, the chain of optionals may return `nil`, so the compiler has to make the type of `street` to be an optional so that it can hold `nil` if that were the result.

When you write this:

```
let street = john.residence?.address?.streetName!
```

This is essentially what your code is doing:

```
var street: String?
if john.residence == nil {
     street = nil
} else if john.residence!.address == nil {
    street = nil
} else {
    // here we have fully unwrapped the street name
    // but it is still assigned to street which
    // is an optional variable
    street = john.residence!.address!.street!
}
```

The only difference being that it is done in one shot so you are able to use `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that to happen is that both `residence` and `address` are optionals, so it's possible that the optional chain evaluates to nil. Hence the entire expression is evaluated as optional.

In order to have a non optional value you have to force unwrap all properties:

```
let street: String = john.residence!.address!.streetName!
```

but of course if any of the optionals in that chain is nil, you will get a runtime exception

Answer (score 1):

The options in your code are there for a reason, you would only want to explicitly unwrap the variables if you already checked the values of the optionals. Your app **will crash** if the value isn't there.

The proper way to unwrap the street name at once is:

```
john.residence!.address!.streetName
```

This unwraps only the `residence` and `address`, if either of those are not set, it will raise an exception. If `streetName` is optional as well, you'll need to add another `!` at the end.

Make sure you're certain about your data structure. It's a good practice to go with non-optionals to begin with, if it will occur that an person wouldn't have an `residence` or `address`, you'll need the optionals. But if you use optionals, make sure they are all checked!

Optionals can make your code safer and easier to read, but you got to use them correctly.